# Sending e-mail without sender's mailbox

Tags: android, email

In my application I send e-mail using `mail.javax`. In this case, I have two e-mail address of the sender and recipient. I would like to send e-mail directly to the recipient. without using the sender's mailbox. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go ahead and specify *spambot* or whatever else.

But be aware that most likely your mail will be either blocked by your provider SMTP or by users mail server.

Comment: No, it's not a spam! In my app I'm sending information to user mailbox. And users are notified of this service.

Comment: Yes, but servers will not care if it's valid mail or a spam. They use rules. One of the often rules applied on SMTP servers is that sender should have a valid mail address. Most of developers in this case would choose *noreply@someserver.com*.

Comment: OK. Then, will be the SMTP block my mailbox if it will be sent to 100 different receivers for 100 messages a day?

Comment: This is up to your provider. Most likely 100 mails per day with valid content will not be considered as spamming and nothing will happen. Otherwise they can block all outgoing mails for that particular IP for particular time period. Just use valid mail header content (incl. sender mail) and everything will be fine.